# RN 0.59.5 with RN-vector-icons 6.4.2 throwing BackAndroid is deprecated and has been removed from this package. Use BackHandler instead

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I just installing newer react native with RNVI and i get this error when using RNVI,

> BackAndroid is deprecated and has been removed from this package. Use BackHandler instead

but everything is fine when i remove `import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';` and `<FontAwesome name="icon_name"/>`

I've tried to search `BackAndroid` using vscode and even on RNVI github repo, but I can't find any `BackAndroid`

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: what routing module are you using and what version of those? I guess this should not be related to the RN-vector-icons module.

Comment: @Yalamber for routing i'm use `"react-navigation": "^3.9.0"`, but i'm confuse if the error not related to RNVI why when i remove RNVI my app running well?

Comment: strange can you share your code or steps to reproduce this error

Comment: @Yalamber i just use this step : `1. react-native init appName`, `2. npm install react-navigation react-native-vector-icons && react-native link`, 3. `use the package` and it would throwing an error. if you said __strange__ so do i, because with lower version of RN and RNVI, there's no problem

Answer (score 0):

### BackAndroid is Deprecated

**Don't Worry we have Backhandler instead of BackAndroid**

**Use "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",**

> ```
> Use Case : 
>
> import { BackHandler } from 'react-native'
>
> componentDidMount() {
>     BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
>   }
>
>   componentWillUnmount() {
>     BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
>   }
>
>   handleBackPress = () => {
>     this.goBack(); // works best when the goBack is async
>     return true;
>   }
> ```