# React native BackAndroid is deprecated and has been removed from this package. Use BackHandler instead

Tags: android, react-native

3 days ago Google came up with a breaking change update - https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases.
This update caused many problems to React native project, mine included. 
I have tried both ways -staying with the old support libraries and migrating to androidX with all dependencies resolved, using:
jetiny, https://gist.github.com/janicduplessis/df9b5e3c2b2e23bbae713255bdb99f3c,
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur/issues/310

with no luck. in the end, I build successfully but bundler comes up with the errors you can see in the screenshot.  I debugged it and it took me to react-native-vector-icons/lic/react-native.js which only "import * from react-native" but something is really off here.

I did see [RN 0.59.5 with RN-vector-icons 6.4.2 throwing BackAndroid is deprecated and has been removed from this package. Use BackHandler instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918055/rn-0-59-5-with-rn-vector-icons-6-4-2-throwing-backandroid-is-deprecated-and-has) and updating to the latest version didn't change anything. I also tried to remove completely this module but then I got some other errors regarding animation values which makes me more suspicious that this is not the way to go. I'm missing something - everything was just fine 3 days ago, and nothing was changed with those libraries.

Errors screenshots can be found here:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur/issues/310

---

### android/app/build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"
    apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
    import com.android.build.OutputFile

    project.ext.react = [
          entryFile: "index.js",
          nodeExecutableAndArgs : ["/usr/local/bin/node"]
    ]

    apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

    def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false
    def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

    android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.moonsite.mimunflex"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 21
        versionName "3.2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
    //          minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
    //          shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-touch-id')
    compile project(':react-native-android-open-settings')
    compile project(':react-native-bottom-action-sheet')
    compile project(':react-native-appsflyer')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-share')
    compile project(':react-native-view-shot')
    compile project(':react-native-blur')
    compile project(':react-native-contacts')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile project(':react-native-detect-navbar-android')
    compile project(':react-native-bottom-sheet-behavior')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }

    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.13.0'

    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-awesome-card-io')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android')
    compile project(':react-native-sensitive-info')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')

    // Firebase dependencies
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"

    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
      implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
      implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'

      implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
      implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
      implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
      implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From 
 node_modules

}
    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.getRequested().getGroup() == 'com.google.android.gms') 
    {
            // If different projects require different versions of
            // Google Play Services it causes a crash on run.
            // Fix by overriding version for all projects.
            // details.useVersion('11.6.0')
        }

    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        // force 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    }

   }

    // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
    // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
    task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

### android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0"
        firebaseVersion = "17.3.4"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur/raw/master/releases/' }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            // url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }

}
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}

 /*

subprojects
        {project ->
            if (project.name.contains('react-native-') ||
                    project.name.contains('react-native-blur')
            ) {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
                }
                buildscript {
                    repositories {
                        google()
                        maven { url = 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/'}
                        jcenter()
                    }
                    dependencies {
                        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
                    }
                }
            }
        }*/
```

---

### package.json

```
{
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  },
  "name": "MY",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "preinstall": "./preinstall.sh",
    "test": "jest",
    "postinstall": "node ./android-release-gradle-fix.js",
    "sa": "react-native run-android",
    "si": "react-native run-ios",
    "ra": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease",
    "cc": "watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*",
    "cm": "rm -rf node_modules/",
    "cmyi": "yarn cm && yarn install",
    "cmar": "yarn cc && yarn cmyi && react-native link && yarn sa"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Faker": "^0.7.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "creditcardutils": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mobx": "^4.1.1",
    "mobx-react": "^5.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "ramda": "^0.25.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-android-open-settings": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-appsflyer": "^1.2.12",
    "react-native-awesome-card-io": "^0.8.2",
    "react-native-axios": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-blur": "^3.2.2",
    "react-native-bottom-action-sheet": "^0.0.18",
    "react-native-bottom-sheet-behavior": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-contacts": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-detect-navbar-android": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-dropdown": "^0.0.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-extra-dimensions-android": "^1.2.5",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-fence-html": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.20.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.4",
    "react-native-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.0.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-pull-to-refresh": "^2.1.3",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-render-html": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-selectme": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-sensitive-info": "^5.2.6",
    "react-native-share": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.7.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.0.7",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-timer-countdown": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-toaster": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.5.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^2.4.0",
    "react-navigation": "1.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.5.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.0",
    "prettier": "1.16.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

### part of error

```
ExceptionsManager.js:82 Warning: Async Storage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-async-storage
reactConsoleErrorHandler @ ExceptionsManager.js:82
console.error @ YellowBox.js:59
printWarning @ warning.js:30
warning @ warning.js:51
warnOnce @ warnOnce.js:29
get AsyncStorage @ react-native-implementation.js:217
(anonymous) @ react-native.js:1
(anonymous) @ react-native.js:1
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ create-icon-set.js:3
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ FontAwesome.js:6
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ myButton.js:4
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ registerHeader.js:4
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ register.js:17
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ navigator.js:6
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ rootHub.js:19
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ app.js:14
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ index.js:2
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:197
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ 8444844f-a756-435b-b388-0f179f51285e:237934
executeApplicationScript @ debuggerWorker.js:40
(anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:72
Show 24 more frames
ExceptionsManager.js:82 Warning: NetInfo has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/netinfo' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo
reactConsoleErrorHandler @ ExceptionsManager.js:82
console.error @ YellowBox.js:59
printWarning @ warning.js:30
warning @ warning.js:51
warnOnce @ warnOnce.js:29
get NetInfo @ react-native-implementation.js:271
(anonymous) @ react-native.js:1
(anonymous) @ react-native.js:1
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ create-icon-set.js:3
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ FontAwesome.js:6
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ myButton.js:4
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ index.js:1
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ registerHeader.js:4
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ register.js:17
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ navigator.js:6
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ rootHub.js:19
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ app.js:14
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:205
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ index.js:2
loadModuleImplementation @ require.js:330
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:197
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ 8444844f-a756-435b-b388-0f179f51285e:237934
executeApplicationScript @ debuggerWorker.js:40
(anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:72
Show 24 more frames
ExceptionsManager.js:74 BackAndroid is deprecated and has been removed from this package. Use BackHandler instead
handleException @ ExceptionsManager.js:74
handleError @ setUpErrorHandling.js:23
reportFatalError @ error-guard.js:42
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:199
metroRequire @ require.js:125
(anonymous) @ 8444844f-a756-435b-b388-0f179f51285e:237934
executeApplicationScript @ debuggerWorker.js:40
(anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:72
infoLog.js:16 Running application "MY" with appParams: {"rootTag":81}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
ExceptionsManager.js:74 Application MY has not been registered.

Hint: This error often happens when you're running the packager (local dev server) from a wrong folder. For example you have multiple apps and the packager is still running for the app you were working on before.
If this is the case, simply kill the old packager instance (e.g. close the packager terminal window) and start the packager in the correct app folder (e.g. cd into app folder and run 'npm start').

This error can also happen due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.


handleException @ ExceptionsManager.js:74
handleError @ setUpErrorHandling.js:23
reportFatalError @ error-guard.js:42
__guard @ MessageQueue.js:316
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:105
(anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:80
```

Answer (score 0):

well, for anyone stumbling upon such errors, in my case it came from a duplicated dev dependency. I'm not sure how it got there but after removing "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0", it's all better.